# Finding duplicates across multiple columns t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following **table**

```
col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4   

1       2       3       1

4       6       1       2

7       5       8       3

0       7       9       4
```

For example, In the above table, the value '1' in the first row(first column) is repeated in the second row(Third column). So I don't need the second row in my result. similarly I want to identify duplicate rows in my existing table and I must display only the rows as in my expected result below. How can I achieve this using t-sql?

Note: Col_4 is the column which identifies each row uniquely. This column should not be included in the duplicate evaluation but should be used to remove duplicate rows as below(ascending order of col_4).

**My Expected result:**

```
col_1   col_2   col_3  

1       2       3       

7       5       8
```

Comment: How are these records sorted to determine which one is "First"? I ask, because I would have chosen `0   7   9` as the correct second record and I see no logic here to stop me from believing that is more correct.

Comment: yup... updated my question... we have a column that identifies each row uniquely... Based on ascending order of that column you can filter out the rows...

Comment: This type of loosey goosey "duplicates" is almost always a sign that the real problem is not in writing this query, but that the problem lies in the architecture of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from table t1 
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from table t2 
                   where t1.col4 < t2.col4 
                   and (    t2.col1 = t1.col1 
                         or t2.col2 = t1.col1
                         or t2.col3 = t1.col1 
                       )
                 )
```

Comment: @ArockiaNirmal Use 'from'

Comment: @ArockiaNirmal Sorry, it sure looks clean to me

Answer (score 0):

> try the solution below. copy and paste to sql studio.

```
 create table cols
 (
 col1 smallint,
 col2 smallint,
 col3 smallint,
  col4 INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 );


 insert into cols
 values(1,2,3),(4,6,1),(7,5,8),(0,7,9),(11,12,13),(17,15,16),(10,17,20),(11,2,3)


select *  from cols

select * from cols where col4 in (
 select t2.col4 from cols t1
  inner join (
   select col1,col2,col3,col4 from cols 
   ) t2 on
    (t1.col1 = t2.col1 or t1.col1 = t2.col2 or t1.col1 = t2.col3 or
    t1.col2 = t2.col1 or t1.col2 = t2.col2 or t1.col2 = t2.col3 or
    t1.col3 = t2.col1 or t1.col3 = t2.col2 or t1.col3 = t2.col3 )
        and t1.col4 > t2.col4
 ) 



 drop table cols
```

Answer (score -1):

Inner join on the same table, doing a comparison against all columns of interest and checking on the unique id to ensure you don't end up with records joining against themselves

```
select mytable a
inner join mytable b on (a.col1 = b.col1 or a.col1 = b.col2 or a.col1 = bcol3 or a.col2 = b.col1 or ...etc...) and a.id != b.id
```

That should get you a list of duplicates. I haven't tested it but I believe that should work.

**edit** - I've tested the above and I can confirm that it works

Comment: List of duplicates is not an answer to the stated question.